# Finding second derivative of sin function

Tags: calculus

so I'm given

```
y' = sec(t)/tan(t)
   = 1/sin(t)
```

I'm then asked to find the derivative of this, and in the example it shows

```
d/dt y' = d/dt (1/sin(t))
        = -cos(t)/sin^2(t)
```

and I have absolutely no idea how they got that last line, could anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Can you tell us a little bit about your level of math education (are you taking a first course in analysis, have you discussed differentiability already, etc.)?

Comment: $\tfrac d{dx}{1\over f(x)}=-{f'(x)\over f^2(x)}$.

Comment: Your subject asks about the second derivative of sin, but the body has no such second derivative.

Answer (score 5):

By the quotient rule,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{\sin{t}} = \frac{\sin{t} \cdot 0 - 1 \cdot \cos{t}}{\sin^2 t} = -\frac{\cos{t}}{\sin^2 t}$$

---

Or by the chain rule,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{\sin{t}} = \frac{d}{dt} (\sin{t})^{-1} = -(\sin{t})^{-2} \cdot \cos{t}$$

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 1):

An informal magic of $d$'s (which corresponds to the chain rule):

Let $w:=\sin(t)$ then we want $\displaystyle\frac{d(1/w)}{dt}$, but that is
$$\frac{d(1/w)}{dt} = \frac{d(1/w)}{dw}\cdot\frac{dw}{dt} = -1/w^2\cdot w'(t) $$

Answer (score 1):

So you're given:

$ y' =\frac{1}{\sin t}=(\sin t)^{-1} $

With the chain rule:

$ y'' = -1 * (\sin t)^{-2} * \frac{d}{dt}\sin t $

Since the derivative of sin(t) is cos(t),

$ y'' = \frac{-1 * \cos t}{(\sin t)^2} $